# How to fix problem with json_encode() via an xml request

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, xml-parsing

So I have a problem with my Code.

This is my index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script>
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          //Nachrichten aus JSON zurueckparsen
          var messages = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          //alle Nachrichten durchgehen
          messages.forEach(function(message) {
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            var messageElement = document.createElement('div');
            messageElement.id = 'message'+message.id;
            messageElement.innerHTML = message.message;
            container.appendChild(messageElement);
            //Onclick Handler für die message hinzufügen
            messageElement.onclick=function() {
              alert('message '+message.id+' clicked');
            }
          });
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "login.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my login.php:

```
<?php
  $ar = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    array_push($ar, array("test", "123"));
  }
  var_dump(json_encode($ar));
?>
```

So like you see I'm trying to make 10 arrays with the array_push method. But when I open the index it says "undefined" and that 10 times. Please help me.

Comment: `$ar` doesn't contain anything with an `id` or a `message`. And why `var_dump`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "undefined" because there are no defined keys for "id" and "message" in your response.

You need to set the keys for response. Try this.

```
<?php
  $ar = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $ar[] = array("id"=>$i, "message"=>"test $i");
  }
  echo json_encode($ar);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In PHP you don't need to use the array_push method to add a new element to the array.
Instead, you use this pattern since PHP extends the array automatically.

$ar[] = [];

```
<?php
  $ar = [];
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $ar[] = ['test', '123'];
  }
  var_dump(json_encode($ar));
?>
```